# WHERE clause limiting results to 50 days from birth date using DATEADD

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get weights of patients for their first 50 days of life. I've tried to filter using DATEADD in the where clause, but it keeps returning rows outside of the 50 day range.

The dates used are in different tables- birthdate is in the patient table, datevalue in the date table. Datevalue is the date a weight was entered into a flowsheet.

```
SELECT
    FlowsheetRowDim.Name,
    FlowsheetRowDim.DisplayName,
    FlowsheetValueFact.Value,
    PatientDim.LastName,
    PatientDim.PrimaryMrn,
    PatientDim.BirthDate,
    DateDim.DateValue 
FROM FlowsheetValueFact
JOIN PatientDim ON FlowsheetValueFact.PatientDurableKey = PatientDim.DurableKey AND PatientDim.IsCurrent = '1' 
JOIN DateDim ON FlowsheetValueFact.DateKey = DateDim.DateKey
JOIN FlowsheetRowDim ON FlowsheetValueFact.FlowsheetRowKey = FlowsheetRowDim.FlowsheetRowKey AND FlowsheetRowDim.DisplayName = 'Weight'
JOIN TimeOfDayDim ON FlowsheetValueFact.TimeOfDayKey = TimeOfDayDim.TimeOfDayKey
WHERE PatientDim.PrimaryMrn ='xxxxxxx' AND DateDim.DateValue >= DATEADD(day,-50, PatientDim.BirthDate)
```

Comment: `DateDim.DateValue >= DATEADD(day,-50, PatientDim.BirthDate)` is getting all dates after 50 days before the patient's birth, I assume there are no measurements before they are born, but this also includes all measurements after birth up until now. I think instead you want something like  `AND DateDim.DateValue >= PatientDim.BirthDate AND DateDim.DateValue <= DATEADD(day,50, PatientDim.BirthDate)`. The first clause may not be necessary (again assuming nothing prior to birth), but it doesn't do much harm, and would remove any potential data entry errors.

Comment: Think about it: `DateDim.DateValue >= DATEADD(day,-50, PatientDim.BirthDate)` This asks for rows where `DateValue` is greater than or equal to the date 50 days **before** the `BirthDate`. You need to *add* 50 days, and check the date is `<=` that date (or perhaps add 51 and it's `<` that date).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your thoughtful replies! I'm on the right path now.